# Cannot create a dataframe in pyspark and write it to Hive table

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I am trying to create a dataframe in pyspark, then write it as a Hive table, and then read it back, but it is not working...

```
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

hive_context = HiveContext(sc) #Initialize Hive

#load the control table 
cntl_dt = [('2016-04-30')]
rdd = sc.parallelize(cntl_dt)
row_cntl_dt = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(load_dt=x[0]))
df_cntl_dt = sqlContext.createDataFrame(row_cntl_dt)
df_cntl_dt.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("schema.cntrl_tbl")
load_dt  = hive_context.sql("select load_dt  from schema.cntrl_tbl" ).first()['load_dt'];
print (load_dt)
```

Prints: 2

I expect :2016-12-31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because:

```
cntl_dt = [('2016-04-30')]
```

is not a valid syntax for a single element `tuple`. Quotes will be ignored and result will be the same as:

```
['2016-04-30']
```

and

```
Row(load_dt=x[0])
```

will give:

```
Row(load_dt='2')
```

Use:

```
cntl_dt = [('2016-04-30', )]
```

Also you're mixing different context (`SQLContext` and `HiveContext`) which is generally a bad idea (and both shouldn't be used in any recent Spark version)